# requests: how to disable / bypass proxy

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting an url with:

```
r = requests.get("http://myserver.com")
```

As I can see in the 'access.log' of "myserver.com", the client's system proxy is used. But I want to disable using proxies at all with `requests`.

Comment: Does adding proxies=None to the request work?

Comment: @Lesleh that is the default for the `proxies` keyword argument, which means it won't change the behavior at all.

Comment: @Lesleh I tried that and unfortunately, it does not work. :(

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The only way I'm currently aware of for disabling proxies *entirely* is the following:

- Create a session
- Set `session.trust_env` to `False`
- Create your request using that session

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False

response = session.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

This is based on [this comment by Lukasa](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/879#issuecomment-10472633) and the (limited) documentation for [`requests.Session.trust_env`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.trust_env).

**Note:** Setting `trust_env` to `False` also ignores the following:

- Authentication information from `.netrc` ([code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L219))
- CA bundles defined in `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` or `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` ([code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L625-L627))

---

If however you only want to disable proxies for a particular domain (like `localhost`), you can use the [`NO_PROXY` environment variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html):

```
import os
import requests

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'stackoverflow.com'

response = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: Has `trust_env=False` any other (side-)effects than disabling the proxy?

Comment: Actually, on one of my servers, `no_proxy` is the correct answer (lower case).

Comment: another trick is to let urllib.getproxies return a not empty dict (urllib.getproxies=lambda: {'z':'z'}). then requests will not get proxy setting from the env and os settings.

Comment: os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = os.environ['NO_PROXY'] + '\,'+ 'stackoverflow.com'
So as to not to replace your default proxies, appending to list will do

Comment: `trust_env = False` solution worked perfectly, thanks for the solution!

Comment: `NO_PROXY` must be `no_proxy`

Comment: `os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'stackoverflow.com'` worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: The environment variables, especially NO_PROXY are a convention rather than a standard. In addition - as some commenters complained that it is 'no_proxy' and not 'NO_PROXY' - in Windows environment variables are case-insensitive, but in Unix systems (MacOS and Linux) they are! The problem in Mac or Unix then is - if someone working at a machine thinks that it is either 'NO_PROXY' or 'no_proxy' and another user assumes the wrong case, bugs are predestined. Thus the `proxy=` argument method is cleaner and always correct.

Answer (score 94):

You can choose proxies for each request. From [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

So to disable the proxy, just set each one to the empty string:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "",
  "https": "",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Update: Switched from `None` to `""`, see comments.

Comment: Did you have check for 2nd case. In my case it's not working i.e. it's still using system proxy.

Comment: @sonukumar What do you mean by "2nd case?"

Comment: oh! I mean using proxies parameter to get method.

Comment: @sonukumar I tested it again and verified it works at least for my system and network. Check the documentation I linked to to see if there's anything else I didn't mention. Of course, you can always ask another question if you can verify it's not working on your system.

Comment: If you are just using HTTP then you don't need to set `"https": None`, for those wondering

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked for me! so much to thank you!

Comment: I recommend against specifying `None`, check my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm coming from 2022 and `None` no longer works, instead it has to be an empty string.

Answer (score 21):

The way to stop requests/urllib from proxying any requests is to set the the `no_proxy` (or `NO_PROXY`) environment variable to `*` e.g. in bash:

```
export no_proxy='*'
```

Or from Python:

```
import os
os.environ['no_proxy'] = '*'
```

To understand why this works is because the [urllib.request.getproxies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.getproxies) function first checks for any proxies set in the environment variables (e.g. `http_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY`, `https_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, etc) or if none are set then it will check for system configured proxies using platform specific calls (e.g. On MacOS it will check using the system scutil/configd interfaces, and on Windows it will check the Registry). As mentioned in the comments if any proxy variables are set you can reset them as @udani suggested, or unset them like this from Python:

```
del os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']
```

Then when urllib attempts to use any proxies the `proxyHandler` function it will check for the presence and setting of the `no_proxy` environment variable - which can either be set to specific hostnames as mentioned above or it can be set the special `*` value whereby all hosts bypass the proxy.

Comment: Using `*` didn't work for me. However, I only had a few exceptions, so listing them explicitly worked great: `export no_proxy='site1.com, site2.domain.com, site3.gov.com'`

Comment: In my case I had a 'HTTP_PROXY' field in the environment variables. Setting the value as os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = '-' fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

With Python3, jtpereyda's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470245/4826457) didn't work, but the following did:

```
proxies = {
    "http": "",
    "https": "",
}
```

Answer (score 5):

requests library respects environment variables.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

So try deleting environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

```
import os
for k in list(os.environ.keys()):
    if k.lower().endswith('_proxy'):
        del os.environ[k]
```

Comment: It definitely does not check the environment variables on a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented [@jtpereyda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470245/2111778)'s solution in our production codebase which worked fine on normal successful HTTP requests (200 OK), but this code ended up not working *when receiving an HTTP redirect (301 Moved Permamently)*. **Instead use**:

```py
requests.get("https://pypi.org/pypi/pillow/9.0.0/json", proxies={"http": "", "https": ""})
```

For comparison, this line causes a `requests.exception.SSLError` when behind a proxy (`pypi.org` tries to redirect us to Pillow with an uppercase P):

```py
requests.get("https://pypi.org/pypi/pillow/9.0.0/json", proxies={"http": None, "https": None})
```

Comment: For more info see this issue: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6153

Answer (score 3):

```
 r = requests.post('https://localhost:44336/api/',data='',verify=False)
```

I faced the same issue when connecting with localhost to access my .net backend from a Python script with the `request` module.

I set `verify` to `False`, which cancels the default SSL verification.

P.s - above code will throw a warning that can be neglected by below one

```py
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
r=requests.post('https://localhost:44336/api/',data='',verify=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have default proxies and you don't want them to be replaced, appending to the list will do the trick:

```
import os
import requests

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = os.environ['NO_PROXY'] + ',' + 'stackoverflow.com' 

response = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

<sup>Posting LeDerp's comment on Lukas Graf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521696/2411320) for future readers.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For those for which `no_proxy="*"` doesnt work, try `0.0.0.0/32`, that worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Henning,
Do you mean adding 0.0.0.0/32  like this?

client.transport.session.proxies = {
    # Utilize for all http/https connections
    'http': "0.0.0.0/32",
    'https': "0.0.0.0/32",
    'no_proxy': "*",
    }