# Curl command in Requests Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying write a python equivalent script for the `cURL`command below using `Requests` library. I am not able to find relevant flags to disable SSL verification and set no proxy.

```
curl -v -k -T debug.zip https://url-to-no-ssl-server/index.aspx --noproxy url-to-no-ssl-server -X POST -H "filename: debug.zip"
```

How do I convert this command to python-requests?

Answer (score 0):

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521696/3579910) shows how to disable proxies:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) for requests has disabling SSL verification:

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

> By default, verify is set to True. Option verify only applies to host certs.

Comment: I tried this before. It still didn't work. I ended up using `urllib2` to write a `curl` equivalent.