# Python requests return 504 in localhost

Tags: python, timeout, python-requests, werkzeug

I run werkzeug server (via Flask) and trying to connect to localhost by requests lib and got 504 error, but if open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in browser - anything ok.

My code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
print(r.content)
```

Response error:

> b'\r\n\r\nERROR: Gateway
>   Timeout\r\n
>
> ### ERROR: Gateway Timeout
>
> \r\n\r\n\r\n
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/:
>
> \r\n
>
> - **Connection
>     refused**
>
> \r\n\r\n
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.\r\n\r\nGenerated Thu, 06 Apr 2017 11:31:09 GMT by
>   10.101.0.1 (Mikrotik HttpProxy)\r\n\r\n'

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify, Response
import geoLocation
import models
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson import json_util



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return 'OK'
....
```

How to connect to localhost (ip + port) via requests lib?

Comment: Which is the code of the flask app?

Comment: Update in question

Comment: Looks like you have a proxy on.

Comment: How you find out it and how i can disable it?

Comment: Are you on linux? can you run: netstat -putan | grep 5000

Comment: On macos sierra

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521535/requests-how-to-disable-bypass-proxy

Comment: bren, thanks os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'stackoverflow.com' worked perfect

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found solution, disable proxy

```
import os
import requests

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Just for the further enlightenment of those who come along later - this is not an unknown issue in requests, see https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/879  Readers may want to investigate the solutions tried there.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I banged my head for almost 3 days....