# Curl requests to an internal website

Tags: curl, network-programming, python-requests

I am trying to use cURL (and python-requests) to retrieve information from a internal website. I have tried

```
curl -v -u "username:password" https://internalwebsite.com/
```

but I keep getting the following error (similar error for python-requests too)

```
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT.
```

Here is an image of the entire error print out.[image: imgur link]

I can access the link using a browser and if I look at the request under the network tab of the developer options of the browser and copy the request as cURL. I get

```
curl "https://internalwebsite.com/" -H "Host: myhosthere" -H "User-Agent: some user agent here" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "Authorization: Basic somebase64stringhere"
```

but this also results in the same error as before.Now I am aware an exact solution to this will be probably hard to find, I just want to collect more information before I ask the IT team about a tool they probably don't support.

Basically I want to know, how is a curl request different from a browser at the server end? The link (Rest API) works absolutely fine through a browser but not through curl, despite using the same user agent of my browser.

There is an "outgoing" proxy that I need to access the internet. Is there also such a thing as an "incoming proxy" that I may need to connect to in order to access the internal website via a curl request? The internal website is only accessible from within the corporate network and all my cURL requests were made from within the corporate network. Seems my browser is authenticated on the network but not cURL?

UPDATE:

For an exact solution, see the comments below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

curl finds an environment variable that tells it to use a proxy so it connects to that and issues a `CONNECT` there, which then gets 502 back...

If you want to disable the proxy for this command line do one of these:

- use `-x ""`
- use `--noproxy` to specify the domain(s) the proxy should not be used for
- remove the environment variable (`*_proxy` something)
- add this domain to the `NO_PROXY` environment variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. However, I have no problem connecting to the internet using the "outgoing" proxy. E.g. "curl -H "Accept: text/plain" https://icanhazdadjoke.com/" works just fine. I have a REST API call (url) on an internal domain that I just cant access with cURL but I can access that link with a browser without any issues.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood in the first instance. Seems by using what I was calling the 'outgoing proxy' which I normally need for curl requests to the internet, I couldn't access the internal websites anymore. By specifying no proxy, I can connect to local network sites. So my solution in this case was `curl --noproxy '*' -u "username:password" https://internalwebsite.com`. For the same solution with python-requests refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470245/1097243).